# How to Drag and Drop between two UITableView in Monotouch USing C# language

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, xamarin.ios

I Have two UItableViews in pad Application in Monotouch using C#.I want to drag and drop a row from one uitableview to another tableview.How can i achieve this.Please reply me....
Note: Language i am using C#.

Answer (score 0):

I know this not your expecting but i am trying to give some idea!!!

I dont have any knowledge on Mono touch but check this below link for drag and drop of an image may be it will give some idea for your problem

http://marcusfollrud.net/2009/09/23/monotouch-how-to-drag-and-drop-image/

And also check below links for creating some customUitableview

http://www.alexyork.net/blog/2011/07/18/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-with-monotouch-the-correct-way/

http://www.infoq.com/articles/monotouch-custom-tables

**Below link code is devleloped in Xcode have a look it and understand it**

[ipad: Drag a UITableViewCell from one UITableViewController and drop it into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506946/ipad-drag-a-uitableviewcell-from-one-uitableviewcontroller-and-drop-it-into-ano/6572871#6572871)

Kiran