# instantiate ViewController With storyboard Identifier in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working in an iOS app that let the user logged in using his Facebook account.
we the user logged in i want to push the profile ViewController filled with the user data ; **sorry for this long preliminary** .

the problem is when i use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method to initiate the profile view controller . its outlet component are all nil

here is the code where i face the problem

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                        user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {    
profileViewController = [self.storyboard        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CGProfileViewController"];
profileViewController.fbProfilePictureView.profileID=user.objectID;
profileViewController.nameLabel.text=user.name;
profileViewController.locationLabel.text=user.location.location.city;

//    [self presentViewController:profileViewController animated:YES completion:nil]
```

}

[image]

is there any problem with my code ? what should i do ?
**Thanking in advance**

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523198/storyboard-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier-not-setting-iboutlets)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you are referencing outlets that haven't yet been created. I would try adding the User model as a property of the view controller (or use some sort of intermediate controller for this), setting the user property in your function above, then in `viewDidAppear` set the text of all the controls appropriately using the User model.

If you do this on the `viewDidAppear` function you can be certain all of your views have been instantiated. this is also better design, after all; why does your LoginViewController class need to know about the internals of `profileViewController`? Encapsulating logic in this way will lead to less problems down the line.

Hope this helps.