# Swift: Cannot change properties in instantiated view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am totally new at Swift so what follows may be a very basic question. Plus it's my first one at stackoverflow.com!

I am getting the "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" while setting text properties of UILabels in an instantiated view controller.

I am making a simple app to show a list of medicines i have at home and their expiry dates. A table view controller shows a list of the medicines, from an array called medArray, and when each one is tapped I want it to load a detail screen with some further details.

I set up a DetailView controller using IB and created the outlet connections of 3 UILabels:

```
//  DetailView.swift
//  HomeMed
//
//  Created by Joao Boavida on 10/12/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 Joao Boavida. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class DetailView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var subtextLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var expdateLbl: UILabel!

}
```

I think the connections are successfully made as the dots on the left gutter are solid. I do get the error when tapping on a table view cell, which calls the following code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let medicine = medArray[indexPath.row]

    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailView") as? DetailView {

        vc.nameLbl.text = medicine.name

        if let subtext = medicine.subtext {
            vc.subtextLbl.text = subtext
        } else {
            vc.subtextLbl.text = ""
        }

        let ISOdateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        ISOdateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withMonth, .withYear, .withDashSeparatorInDate]

        vc.expdateLbl.text = "Exp: \(ISOdateFormatter.string(from: medicine.expiry))"

        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }

}
```

I get the error as soon as I try to access vc.nameLbl.text, which is nil for reasons I don't know. vc.expdateLbl and vc.subtextLbl are also nil.

The "vc" view controller seems to be instantiated correctly because if I omit the configuration code and push it just after creating it it displays fine, albeit with the initial text in the labels that I set in IB. It is only when I try to change those labels that it crashes.

I have tried making and remaking the outlet connections with no success. Can anyone help troubleshooting this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The outlets aren't actually setup until after viewDidLoad() I would try moving the text setting somewhere later in its lifecycle.

Comment: The reason why you are getting this error because `vc` outlets with be *not* be instantiated yet. Are you using segues anyway?

Comment: `vc.nameLbl` is not initalized yet. The VC loaded, but not its IBOutlets. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523198/storyboard-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier-not-setting-iboutlets Instead, use a `String` property to store the name, and in do `vc.myNameStringProperty = medicine.name`,  `viewDidLoad()` do `self.nameLbl.txt = myNameStringProperty`

Comment: When reviewing the duplicate, see this specific answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49818897/1226963

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy and everyone, the problem is solved! I had seen that post but not that specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your VC's outlets here, right?

```
    vc.nameLbl.text = medicine.name <---

    if let subtext = medicine.subtext {
        vc.subtextLbl.text = subtext <---
    } else {
        vc.subtextLbl.text = "" <---
    }
    ...
    vc.expdateLbl.text = "Exp: \(ISOdateFormatter.string(from: medicine.expiry))" <---
```

The outlets `nameLbl`, `subtextLbl` and `expdateLbl` are all nil when the above code is run. They are not set at that point in time yet.

The outlets *are* already set when `viewDidLoad` is called. Therefore, what you can do is to add three properties in your `DetailView`:

```
var name: String!
var subtext: String!
var expdate: String!
```

Instead of setting the outlets, you set the above three properties:

```
    vc.name = medicine.name <---

    if let subtext = medicine.subtext {
        vc.subtext = subtext <---
    } else {
        vc.subtext = "" <---
    }
    ...
    vc.expdat = "Exp: \(ISOdateFormatter.string(from: medicine.expiry))" <---
```

Then, in the `DetailView`, assign the properties to the `text` of the labels in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    nameLbl.text = name
    subtextLbl.text = subtext
    expdateLbl.text = expdate
}
```

Comment: FYI - this is all covered in the duplicate answer I linked.

Comment: @JoaoB If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark.

Answer (score -2):

It crashes because your are trying to access a `UILabel` before it is loaded. So, you should call `vc.loadViewIfNeeded()`. This will load all the `UIViewController` views.