# Drag to Delete - UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

So we've all probably seen Facebook's method of removing messenger chat heads from the view, I want to implement a similar method of deletion, however to collection view cells within a collection view. When there is a long press on a cell, a box would appear at the bottom of the view and the user would be able to drag the cell to the box for deletion, or simply let go of the select cell and thus returning to it original position and state.

I am aware of two libraries that allow collection view cells to be dragged around and reordered and was going to attempt to use those to implement such a feature, however they allow complete reordering of cells within a collection view and I figured there may be an existing library for implementing my desired feature, or a simpler method.

So basically my question is, what's the best method of implementing this feature into a collection view and if you are aware of a library that allows this easily, it'd be great if you could share it.

Code examples are always welcome and make things a lot easier.

Collection view cell re-ordering libraries: [LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout](https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout) and [DraggableCollectionView](https://github.com/lukescott/DraggableCollectionView)

I understand how to go about deleting the collection view cells, i'm more interested in the method of deletion. *

Comment: I have the same problem need to resolve. I recommend the link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506946/ipad-drag-a-uitableviewcell-from-one-uitableviewcontroller-and-drop-it-into-ano] maybe it'll helpful for you.