# I have four uitableview in one view controller i want to drag rows from one tableview to another tableview like first to third or fourth randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have four `UITableView` in one view controller,i want to drag rows from one `UITableView` to another `UITableView` like first to third or first to fourth Randomly.
I Tried moving from first `UITableView` to second `UITableView` its working,But i am looking for random move.

Comment: Post your code what you had done so far. So everyone can know where you are doing wrong

Comment: This is what I had referred to achieve the above functionality,
Very efficiently done, you can have a look just in case
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506946/ipad-drag-a-uitableviewcell-from-one-uitableviewcontroller-and-drop-it-into-ano

Comment: You can check this out : https://github.com/ice3-software/between-kit/tree/master/Legacy

Comment: @iOSGeek i tried this sample but i can't able to place the cell in another tableview

Comment: @SunnyShah : I have 4 items[rows] in first tableview,i want to split the items like 1 item in one tableview another item in another tableview remaining two items in first tableview. i want to drag/select items from first tableview and place/drop to any other tableview like random. i want solution for this scenario.. pls Help me..

Comment: @7vikram7: i will try and let you know..